# How to access object.pk in a function listview without having to iterate through the objects with a for loop?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views, django-tables2

I have a FBV using django-tables2 so the the template already call the objects but i need to add a button that triggers a modal so I need to call the pk of the objects inside the button

here's the views.py

```
def Patients_list(request):

  patients = Patient.objects.filter(user=request.user)
  table = PatientTable(patients)
  RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

  return render(request, 'patients/patients_list.html',{
'table' : table,
'patients':patients,
})
```

and the button is callable at the tables.py

```
class PatientTable(tables.Table):

FirstName = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))
LastName = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))
Telephone_no = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))

delete = TemplateColumn('<button type ="button" class ="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete" >Deleta</button>',extra_context={'patient': 'Patient'})

class Meta:
    model = Patient
    attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-hover'}
    exclude = ("user", "Notes", "Adress")
    template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
```

and the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block content %}

<div id="content">

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <h1> Patients list: </h1>
    <br>

    <a href="{%url 'patients:patient_create'%}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Add Patient</a>
    <br>
    <br>

    {% render_table table %}

    {% else %}

      <h2>please login</h2>

    {% endif %}

</div>

 <div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalDelete"
  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Delete patient!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this patient?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <form method="POST" action="{% url 'patients:patient_delete' pk=patients.pk %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="btn btn-danger" value="Yes" type="submit" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  {% endblock %}
```

so when i call the patient.pk in this page it always return an error :

```
Reverse for 'patient_delete' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['patients/delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

but when i call the same url(with a different name if it's in another context) it worked and every FBV listview tutorial calls the objects in a different scenario using a for loop so how I can achieve that without using the for loop how can I imply that in my scenario here ?

I tried every other method of calling the pk even by

```
pk=patients.pk
pk=pk
```

I've been stuck on this for over 10 days now asking here and on forums so any help is really appreciated,I'm really desperate.Thanks.

Comment: But without a loop, **which patient** do you want to get the pk from?

Comment: That's the idea I want it for every patient! so how can I make that possible in a case like this using django-tables2 ?
Is there any other way of rendering a table this dynamic and making the modal possible ?

Comment: But still none of this makes sense. If you want it for every patient, *then you need to do it in a loop*. You can put the modal in the loop, or you can create the link in the loop and use some Javascript to extract it from there and assign it to the modal, but there is simply no other way of getting an ID for every item in a collection without using some kind of loop. That's not even programming, that's just simple logic.

Comment: I'm rewriting the view using a generic.list view and I will manually render the table thanks for your help!